# Best Practice: AdMob ads at top or bottom?

Tags: android, ios

So, I just integrated AdMob into my application. Now, I'm wondering whether to place the Ads on the top of the screen or the bottom.

Aesthetically, I think the App looks better with the ads on the bottom of the screen.

However, the little devil in me is thinking that there's more likelihood of people clicking on the ads by mistake (thereby increasing my click count), if I place them at the top since that's where I have the action bar.

Of course people who genuinely want to click on ads will click them no matter where I place them.

Can anyone share their experience in this regard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [AdMob Publisher Guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307237?hl=en) cover this:

> Ads should not be placed very close to or underneath buttons or any other object which users may accidentally click while interacting with your application.

and also:

> Ads should not be placed in areas where users will randomly click or place their fingers on the screen. For applications that involve this type of interaction, we recommend implementing our ads on a title or ending page.

As others have mentioned, place ads where they will **not** be accidentally hit.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks +1.

Comment: @kabuko What about the virtual "hardware" buttons of newer Android devices which are right at the bottom of the screen and the ActionBar which is at the top of the screen. Both are regularly used areas with buttons. So basically by that definition it is not allowed to put ads at the top nor at the bottom of the screen. And the middle area is not allowed either. How to deal with that scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Of course people will be more likely to click your ad (accidentally or on purpose), but your customer's satisfaction will also be likely to drop (especially when someone accidentally hits your ad). When an ad affects the usability of an app the chance that a user will delete your app is quite likely, which results in nil income.

If you really need to incorporate ads in your app, I would place them at a place where the user is the least likely to accidentally tap them. As the iPhone's screen is not that large, in terms of visibility this will not have any serious effect. (I personally dislike any app that uses ads and especially AdMob ads, but that is a personal note).

Answer (score 0):

With the soft buttons found on many of the latest phones I don't think positioning your ads at the top of the screen will increase your CTR, as users are likely just as likely to accidentally touch ads at the bottom of the screen.

Go with where you think the ad looks better (most likely the bottom).